# I keep unable to find the Dockerfile path in the yml file of github actions

Tags: docker, github-actions, cicd

The current folder structure is

```
.github

front folder
 -Dockerfile
```

It's like this,
When Github actions are executed, an error that the Dockerfile cannot be found continues to occur.

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong, but I'd like to ask for help.

### - error message

```
Error: buildx failed with: ERROR: failed to solve: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount2707662202/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
```

- main.yml

```
    if: needs.path_changes.outputs.front == 'true'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Login to Docker Hub
        uses: docker/login-action@v3
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_TOKEN }}

      - name: Set up Docker Meta for Frontend
        id: docker_meta_frontend
        uses: docker/metadata-action@v5
        with:
          images: front

      - name: Build and Push Frontend Docker Image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v5
        with:
          context: ./front
          file: ./Dockerfile
          platforms: linux/amd64
          push: true
          tags: ${{ steps.docker_meta_frontend.outputs.tags }}
          labels: ${{ steps.docker_meta_frontend.outputs.labels }}
```